# internet connectivity status using SCNetwork leaks

Tags: objective-c, connection

Trying to build up simple function to get internet status, but getting leaks every time I call this function:

```
+ (BOOL) connectionStatus
{
    BOOL retVal = NO;
    const char *hostName = [@"google.com"
                            cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reach = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, hostName); // Attempt to ping google.com
    SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reach, &flags); // Store reachability flags in the variable, flags.

    if(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable & flags) {
        // Can be reached using current connection.
    }

    if(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionAutomatic & flags) {
        // Can be reached using current connection, but a connection must be established. (Any traffic to the specific node will initiate the connection)
    }

    if(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN & flags) {
        // Can be reached via the carrier network
    } else {
        // Cannot be reached using the carrier network
    }

    if((kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable & flags) && !(kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN & flags)) {
        // Cannot be reached using the carrier network, but it can be reached. (Therefore the device is using wifi)
        retVal = YES;
    } else if (kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN & flags) {
        // Using the carrier network
        retVal = YES;
    } else {
        // No connection available.
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Instruments shows leaks and always point as responsible frame SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags and SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags from SystemConfiguration . 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you done with 'reach' do

```
CFRelease(reach);
```